# Loading table in ArcMap gives Serious Application Error?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, relationship-class, geometric-network, serious-application-error

I am an ArcGis 10. ( ArcEditor licence) user and I have a problem when trying to load data with the Load Objects Tool in ArcMap.

I want to load a table, but after I choose the input data (equipment.dbf) - Add- and press next , ArcMap instantly shuts down and the well known window appears:

> ArcGis Desktop has encountered a serious application error and is
>   unable to continue.

One more thing, I am trying to load the table into a file geodatabase with a geometric network and relationship classes (but that shouldn't be a problem as support says).

Does anyone know why, and what is the solution?

Comment: Does it happen with all .dbf files, or just with equipment.dbf?  Does it happen when loading into an empty file geodatabase?

Comment: check that there are no special characters in the field names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very hard to tell without seeing the 'equipment.dbf' file, but my guess is that there is something about the data file that Arc doesn't like.  I wonder if there is something about the DBF schema that is unusual/unexpected (since it is failing at the schema test).  In addition to Kirk's question, have a look at:

1. Do the field names conform to a strict interpretation of the dbf spec (no commas or other 'odd' characters and not longer than about 12 characters)?
2. Does this file open with Excel?   If so, then the file itself is probably not corrupt.  If no, your file is corrupt in some way.
3. Can you load the file into the table of contents?  If 'yes' to '2' but 'no' to '3', then the file contains some non-conformance but isn't corrupt.
4. Do you get the same problem if you try using the ArcCatalog Simple Loader (I would expect so).

Work-around suggestions: If you can't spot anything wrong with the dbf file, can you import it as XY data, convert to a shapefile and then use that (perhaps with a Union on your target file or through the loader)?

Comment: +1 does it open in excel?

Comment: Hello Sylvestener:P First of all I would like to thank you for helping me again. Now, what I've got: 1.checked the files again, no comma, 8 characters, just letters- still no. 2. opened it with an excel, it worked -still no. 3. load it in the table of contents, visualize it - but still no. 4. tried to load it in ArcCatalog, and I get the message "Cannot load into non simple data". Have no idea. Does it matter if i'm trying to load a dbf. in a file geodatabase table? Isn't it possible? 10x again

Comment: It is NOT just because you are trying to load a DBF in a file-based geodatabase.  It ought to work.  The only clue we have here is the error from ArcCatalog.  Are you trying to load into a feature class or a table?  Can you try one more test: can you load your dbf into an new empty table (set up a test-table with a couple of fields).  If so, we can be sure the dbf is OK and switch our attention.

Comment: I'm loading in a File Geodatabase table. So from table to table. Tried your new test :P guess what? It didn't worked:))) ÄrcGIs has ecountered a serious application error and is unable to continue...bla bla bla...please tell esri about this problem:P...I DID.. contacted ESRI Romania..they didn't know either:P

Comment: OK I'm clutching at straws now, but do you have the latest service pack?  I'm using Arc 10 SP 3 and don't have this problem.

Comment: ArcGis 10.0, Service Pack 0

Comment: Installed Service Pack 4. Evrika:P                                    arcmap doesn't close anymore, but apparently I can't load data from a table intro another table.

Comment: That's odd because I have loaded data from a CSV into a table and from a dbf into a feature class.  In fact I did just that a few hours ago!  Maybe I'm not supposed to and that was a loophole they closed with SP4 :).  Here's a work around though: join all your tables together outside of Arc (you can use anything - Postgresql, heck even Excel as long as it doesn't have more than 65536 rows and 256 columns in total), then load into Arc and then right-click in TOC ->Data->Export and dump it into your geodatabase that way - sure it's nasty but it should work:)

Comment: The "Excel solution" is frustrating, it takes time. Do you have any idea what does "Cannot load into non simple data" error means? It appears when trying with the Simple Data Loader.

Comment: I'm not sure TBH.  Since you're loading from a table into a table and not involving feature classes, it can't relate to non-conformance with the simple-features specification.  I can only assume that there is something about your destination table because I have no problem doing this sort of operation.   However, that's why I got you to make a fresh table - to try and eliminate the destination table as an issue - but that didn't work.  Without seeing the data I am out of ideas.  Can you upload a sample of your table somewhere so I can take a look at it?

Answer (score 1):

According to an ESRI Product Engineer, you cannot load table to table with Load Objects in ArcMap, the only possibility is using Simple Data Loader in ArcCatalog. But of course in this case you cannot have relationship classes, geometric network interfering. Unfortunately he is right.